# Resize object and materials change appearance

Tags: materials

I've got a beautiful 3rd-party payware product by a competent artist. The issue is that when I resize the object for use in another project (it needs to be resized to match the dimensions of the other project), the materials change dramatically.

I realize this may be a RTFM moment, but I'm wondering if there is something basic that can be addressed to fix this issue? Thanks. Blender 2.93.5, Cycles, Windows 10

[image]

Comment: Is it maybe the case that the material works properly after resizing, but once you apply scale it breaks?

Comment: Markus von Broady, thank you for the response. One or more of the shaders have scale-specific values maybe? I don't know. Like everything else Blender, I'll probably figure it out eventually. :)

Comment: You didn't answer my question, but if it was supposed to be "yes", then the answer could be to multiply/divide each *object* coordinate used in the material.

Comment: Markus von Broady, thank you again for the response. No, I did not answer your question because I did not understand it. I think of resizing and scaling as the same thing via the Scale tool, but you're suggesting it might be two steps? 

1) resize; 
2) apply scale?

Comment: Screenshots of the material node setup and outliner would help to investigate the issue.

Comment: Good suggestion. I'd share, but since this is a product I purchased I'm reluctant post the artist's node setup. I recall several years ago when rescaling objects in Blender that bump map values would not scale proportionately, at least the way I was doing it. Scale an object down and the bump depths would become much more pronounced, so I suspect something along the same lines is happening here.